# Pasar minutos en formato int a formato HH:MM SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Estoy dando vuelta al intentar pasar un valor entero a formato `hh:mm`.

Hasta ahora logré hacerlo `/60`, pasando el resto a minutos y casteando todo en formato *string* para que me queden los puntos `:` en el medio. Pero necesitaría que quede en formato time para poder hacer cálculos:

Ejemplo:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
| Legajo | PromEntMin | HoraEntrada | MinutosEntrada| Entrada |
---------------------------------------------------------------
|200     |  648       |    10       |   48          |   10:48 |
---------------------------------------------------------------
|202     |  497       |    8        |   17          |   8:17  | 
---------------------------------------------------------------
|203     |  596       |    9        |   56          |   9:56  | 
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

¿Como puedo formatear estos valores en SQL?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el [recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y lee 
[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Tengo una inquietud, ¿la información que muestras es la que guardas en una tabla de base de datos? y si es así, ¿cuáles columnas estás usando para formatear a `hh:mm`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si estas usando SqlServer 2008:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (
LEGAJO INT,
PROMENT INT,
HORA INT,
MINUTO INT
)
DECLARE @TIEMPO TIME = '00:00:00'

INSERT INTO @T VALUES (200,648,10,48 )
INSERT INTO @T VALUES (202,497 ,8 ,17 )

SELECT LEGAJO, PROMENT, HORA, MINUTO,DATEADD(MINUTE, MINUTO, DATEADD(HOUR, HORA, @TIEMPO)) AS TIEMPOMANIPULABLE
FROM @T
```

Enlace Fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/10322

Gracias a @Davlio por la sugerencia con TIMEFROMPARTS SqlServer 2012 - 2014:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (
LEGAJO INT,
PROMENT INT,
HORA INT,
MINUTO INT
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES (200,648,10,48 )
INSERT INTO @T VALUES (202,497 ,8 ,17 )

SELECT LEGAJO, PROMENT, HORA, MINUTO,TIMEFROMPARTS(HORA, MUNUTO, 0, 0, 0) AS TIEMPOMANIPULABLE
FROM @T
```

Enlace Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7d/4389/0

Comment: Por el tag `sql-server-2014`, ya podría usar `TIMEFROMPARTS` sin necesidad de estar agregando por partes. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213398.aspx

Answer (score -1):

En el caso de SQLServer, por ejemplo, tienes una función que te convertirá un `STRING` en un `DATETIME`.
Con la función `Convert` podrás hacer algo similar a esto:

```
UPDATE MiTabla SET MiCampo = CONVERT(datetime, '2017/02/16 10:00:00', 120)
```

Según el SGBD que estés utilizando (si es otro) es posible que exista algo similar.